# CSRF verification fails when trying to login in an already logged in application Django

Tags: python, django

Here is what I did:

1. I have two tabs open on my browser, and I have the login form loaded in both the tabs.
2. I login with the required credentials on first tab.
3. I again try to login by providing the credentials on the second tab.
4. I get an error on the second tab : `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

I have used the `{% csrf_token %}` in my login form and  `CsrfViewMiddleware` in `settings.py`.

Also, I tried the same with the default admin application and got the same error.

Comment: The CSRF token changes per season by default. Why anyone do that I wonder? What is the expected behaviour? Do you have `DEBUG=TRUE`?

Answer (score 6):

This is to be expected. The login operation rotates the CSRF token, otherwise it would be possible to use the token from outside the authenticated session.

Hence what happens in your case:

1. Retrieve login page in Tab 1 (with unauthenticated "form" CSRF token)
2. Retrieve login page in Tab 2 (with unauthenticated "form" CSRF token)
3. Login in Tab 1, CSRF "cookie" token gets cycled server side, browser cookie gets updated
4. Try to login in Tab 2, sends new cookie (tabs do not separate sessions), but old "form" token.
5. Second login request is rejected (because "form" token and "cookie" token mismatch).

This is an interaction between the fact that using multiple browser tabs do not separate sessions and the fact that the login operation cycles the "cookie" CSRF token sent to you by the server.

Any page loaded *before* the login operation that takes place in the same session (e.g. in a different browser tab) will now have an incorrect CSRF "form" token.

Comment: Above approach can work. Also don't refresh and send a new token for every new request. If you would have kept one token per session, you wouldn't be facing such problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
Is there any fix/workaround for the above situation??

Comment: Rather than using tabs, you can open a new browser window, or a different browser

Comment: @ashu I think it's common practice to exempt the login form from CSRF verification. Since login is establishing the validity of credentials in the first place, there is no authenticated session to hijack, yet. You still cannot use a django app with different usernames in separate tabs, though. Last tab to login wins as django's sessions are cookie based and cookies are shared between tabs.

Comment: If I remove the "{% csrf_token %}" from my login form,I get the error "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted".

Comment: Removing the token from the template does not make the login view work without CSRF, it rather makes the login not work at all, because you now never send the token the server expects. Instead, you need to decorate the view with [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

Comment: "I think it's common practice to exempt the login form from CSRF verification." That's not good, since Login CSRF is an security risk too.

Answer (score 0):

### Server side approach: Redirect

Please note it is a security risk to mark your login view as CSRF exempt. Pre login sessions are used to  mitagate various [CSRF attacks](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#login-csrf). The destroying of the anonymous session is a security feature.

I solved if with a custom CSRF view. Before showing the custom CSRF view, it first checks if it is a login attempt, and the user is already logged in. If the user is already logged in, then just redirect to the next url.

```py
# settings.py
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'some.path.to.your.views.error_403_csrf_failure'


# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def error_403_csrf_failure(request, reason=""):
    """
    To fix this issue:
        1. User opens tab A and tab B, and both show the login in form.
        2. User logs in on tab A, this will destroy the Anonymous session, and create a new one (for security)
        3. Then user logs in on tab B
            - The CSRF token for the Anonymous session is now invalid
            - Since the user is already logged, we just redirect them to refresh the page
    """
    if request.path == '/accounts/login/' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        next = request.GET.get('next', '/')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

    url = reverse('login') + '?next=' + request.path
    context = {
        'page_title': "Authentication Error",
        'continue_url': url,
        'reason': reason,
    }
    response = render(request, "core.base/403_csrf.html", context=context)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

### Client side approach: Update CSRF Token before POST

An alternate approach is you can update the CSRF token from the cookie (which would of been updated in an alternate tab), whereas the CSRF token in the form would have remained the same.

```
const FORM = document.querySelector('form');
const CSRFToken = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('csrftoken=')).split('=')[1];
// If the user logs out then logs in again, this will use the new Cookie CSRF Token and work
document.querySelector('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value = CSRFToken;
```

Esnure you have the following settings:

```py
# settings.py
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True  # Default: False - Means will only send cookie via HTTPS (not HTTP)
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False  # Default: False - Store CSRF token in Session as opposed to in cookie
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False  # Default: False - True = client JavaScript cannot access the cookie
```

### Side Note:  If you have custom login view

If you have rolled your own login view (e.g. say you wish to login with email instead of username), and you view inherits from `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`, If you wish to automatically redirect your user if the land of the login page:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    ...
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
```